# how to create maven mojo plugin to overwrite files directories in target project

Tags: maven, plugins, implementation, mojo

I am writing a maven plugin which generates java source code based on input text file and some additional configuration.
e.g. User creates maven project and adds my plugin in his project's pom.xml as below -

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>abc.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>abc</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <schemaPath>${basedir}\input</schemaPath>
            <package>com.svc.xyz</package>
            <fileNametxt>${basedir}\input.txt</fileNametxt>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

As part of executing the goal of my plugin, i would like the plugin delete all the pre existing java source files/directories in user's project as well as rewrite pom.xml of user project.
Plugin should regenerate user project's pom.xml taking existing contents and also keep some other existing user project resources like schema Directory.
Also,I don't want user of plugin to do any editing after generation of source code and would prefer to directly 'compile package' the generated source code in user project by the plugin. 
Since plugin will regenerate users' pom.xml itself, may be need to create a new maven project altogether with generated source code, compile, package and have jar created?

Comment: *rewrite pom.xml of target project from the plugin i am developing*? The plugin is packaged in a JAR, you can't rewrite its POM like that. What are you trying to do? I'm not sure I understand. If you want to delete files, pass a parameter to your `abc-maven-plugin` pointing to the base directory of the files to delete.

Comment: I want user to add my plugin in his maven project and plugin generate everything based on configuration he enters, without writing anything manually.

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what plugin are for. I still don't see the particular issue you have with deletion of files. Can you describe more?

Comment: Edited the description, let me know if it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Rewriting the POM of the user doesn't sound like something the user would appreciate very much... It's also very error-prone: generated content should **never** be placed in source directories. What concrete problem do you want to solve? You can generate Java source code, add it to the build path of the project, and remove previous files without changing the POM at any time.

Comment: i need  to add few dependencies without altering existing content. i want to generate ready to deploy project/service based on input files.

Comment: Add dependencies? Why? [See this thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/How-to-add-a-dependency-dynamically-during-the-build-in-a-plugin-td116484.html), that's not a good idea. It's still unclear what the global task is. What's the macro thing you want to achieve?